# How to make Android's ellipsizing more "even" with multiple TextViews?

Tags: android, layout, textview, ellipsize

I have two `TextView`s in a `TableLayout`. Both have `android:ellipsize="end"` and are in `android:shrinkColumns`. The goal is that if there is enough space, both `TextView`s will be shown in full (without taking up extra space), but if there isn't enough space, they should both ellipsize.

This works for the most part, except when one `TextView` is significantly longer than the other. In that case, the shorter `TextView` will be "squished" by the larger `TextView`, often to the point of just being `...`.

Is there a way to have Android apply the ellipsize more evenly (with regard to screen space)? I do not know which `TextView` is longer at runtime since they're loaded from the internet. I also cannot use a minimum width as sometimes the text is just really short.

#### Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="0,1">

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Short" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Long Text" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="0,1">

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Short" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Text" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="0,1">

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Short" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Text" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot Of Example]

As can be seen in the example, the more text I add to the "Long Text" `TextView`, the less of the "Short" `TextView` is visible. My goal is to have it always be something like row #2, both ellipsized, but at least some content visible in both.